# How to display nodes in order on a daily base

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I would like to display node of a specific content type with views.
I want one node to be display every day in order based on node id and the node to change every day.

Comment: Can't you add a date field to a node, to indicate on what dates it will be shown? It would make things easier, both from code POV, and from redactor's POV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [views random seed module](https://drupal.org/project/views_random_seed) and on the sort criteria use Global: Random seed
and set the reset seed to everyday

> Adds a random order handler with seed. If a constant integer argument
>   N is specified in the sql RAND() function, it is used as the seed
>   value, which produces a repeatable sequence of column values. This
>   makes it possible to have paging and not having items show up twice.
>   It's also possible to compute a custom seed using PHP, allowing you to
>   create pseudo randoms numbers based on variables such as the date of
>   the day.

Comment: This does not meet "order based on node id" criteria.